# Compiler mov'es this pointer to wrong address

Tags: c++, assembly, this, msvc12

I have a simple polymorphic construction, with one pure virtual function `Foo`.
The only flaw in the big project it's used in is that the project uses a couple of global statics for centralized parameter loading and for event logging (can't easily get rid of that legacy code).

Project info:

- Platform toolset: `v110_xp`
- MFC in static library
- MBCS charset
- calling convention: `__cdecl`
- All optimizations disabled
- Warning level 4, no warnings on the whole project

Code:

```
class Base
  {
public:
  Base(){}
  virtual ~Base(void){}
  virtual void Foo(void) = 0;
  };

class Derived
  : public Base
  {
public:
  Derived(void) : Base(){}
  virtual void Foo(void) override
    {
    double a = sqrt(4.9);
    double b = -a;
  }
```

Calling code (doesn't really matter, same behaviour everywhere)

```
BOOL MainMFCApp::InitInstance()
  {
  Derived* d = new Derived();
  d->Foo();
  delete d;

  ...
  }
```

The problem is that when run in debug (not tested with release), and when we end up inside function `Foo`, the `this` pointer is 'corrupted':

- `this = 0xcccccccc`
- `this.__vfptr = <unable to read memory>`

When I dive into the assembly code entering the function I see the following:

```
    13: 
    14: 
    15: void Derived::Foo(void)
    16:       {
015E3570 55                   push        ebp  
015E3571 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
015E3573 83 E4 F8             and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
015E3576 81 EC EC 00 00 00    sub         esp,0ECh  
015E357C 53                   push        ebx  
015E357D 56                   push        esi  
015E357E 57                   push        edi  
015E357F 51                   push        ecx  
015E3580 8D BD 14 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0ECh]  
015E3586 B9 3B 00 00 00       mov         ecx,3Bh  
015E358B B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
015E3590 F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
015E3592 59                   pop         ecx  
015E3593 89 8C 24 F0 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [esp+0F0h],ecx  
    17:   double a = sqrt(4.9);
015E359A F2 0F 10 05 00 55 09 02 movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr ds:[2095500h]  
015E35A2 E8 72 D4 FD FF       call        __libm_sse2_sqrt_precise (015C0A19h)  
015E35A7 F2 0F 11 84 24 E0 00 00 00 movsd       mmword ptr [esp+0E0h],xmm0  
    18:   double b = -a;
015E35B0 F2 0F 10 84 24 E0 00 00 00 movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [esp+0E0h]  
015E35B9 66 0F 57 05 10 55 09 02 xorpd       xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[2095510h]  
015E35C1 F2 0F 11 84 24 D0 00 00 00 movsd       mmword ptr [esp+0D0h],xmm0  
    19:   return;
    20:       }
015E35CA 5F                   pop         edi  
015E35CB 5E                   pop         esi  
015E35CC 5B                   pop         ebx  
015E35CD 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
015E35CF 5D                   pop         ebp  
015E35D0 C3                   ret  
--- No source file -------------------------------------------------------------
015E35D1 CC                   int         3  
...
015E35EF CC                   int         3
```

Breakpoint at line 17, right before entering the function body: Using the watch window to inspect the object behind register `ecx` (with a cast to `Derived*`) shows that `ecx` contains the pointer I need (to the object), but for some reason it is `mov`'ed to the seemingly random address `[esp+0F0h]`.

And now the really interesting/flabbergasting part: When I change

```
double b = -a;
```

to

```
double b = -1.0 * a;
```

and compile again, everything magically works. The function assembly has now changed to:

```
    13: 
    14: 
    15: void Derived::Foo(void)
    16:       {
00863570 55                   push        ebp  
00863571 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00863573 81 EC EC 00 00 00    sub         esp,0ECh  
00863579 53                   push        ebx  
0086357A 56                   push        esi  
0086357B 57                   push        edi  
0086357C 51                   push        ecx  
0086357D 8D BD 14 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0ECh]  
00863583 B9 3B 00 00 00       mov         ecx,3Bh  
00863588 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
0086358D F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
0086358F 59                   pop         ecx  
00863590 89 4D F8             mov         dword ptr [this],ecx  
    17:   double a = sqrt(4.9);
00863593 F2 0F 10 05 00 55 31 01 movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr ds:[1315500h]  
0086359B E8 79 D4 FD FF       call        __libm_sse2_sqrt_precise (0840A19h)  
008635A0 F2 0F 11 45 E8       movsd       mmword ptr [a],xmm0  
    18:   double b = -1.0 * a;
008635A5 F2 0F 10 05 10 55 31 01 movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr ds:[1315510h]  
008635AD F2 0F 59 45 E8       mulsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [a]  
008635B2 F2 0F 11 45 D8       movsd       mmword ptr [b],xmm0  
    19:   return;
    20:       }
008635B7 5F                   pop         edi  
008635B8 5E                   pop         esi  
008635B9 5B                   pop         ebx  
008635BA 81 C4 EC 00 00 00    add         esp,0ECh  
008635C0 3B EC                cmp         ebp,esp  
008635C2 E8 32 CD FC FF       call        __RTC_CheckEsp (08302F9h)  
008635C7 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
008635C9 5D                   pop         ebp  
008635CA C3                   ret  
--- No source file -------------------------------------------------------------
008635CB CC                   int         3  
...
008635EF CC                   int         3
```

Now the generated code nicely moves the pointer in register `ecx` to `this`. Other difference:

- different memory addresses/offsets
- `mulsd` instead of `xorpd` to negate the variable
- `and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h` disappeared (?? used to align the stack pointer `esp` ??)
- more cleanup (after the function body)?? (`add cmp call`)

The assembly part where the parameters get pushed to the stack is the same for both situations:

```
    53:   d->Foo();
011A500B 8B 45 E0             mov         eax,dword ptr [d]  
011A500E 8B 10                mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
011A5010 8B F4                mov         esi,esp  
011A5012 8B 4D E0             mov         ecx,dword ptr [d]  
011A5015 8B 42 04             mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+4]  
011A5018 FF D0                call        eax
```

Of course when I try to replicate this with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, everything works as intened. But in my big project, it fails consistently.
I'm not sure which parameters can influence compilation, and don't know enough of assembly to even see what's going on there;
therefor I'm asking here in the hope that someone has seen this before or recognizes this behaviour.

Note: it also works again, when I remove the `sqrt` call.

---

Update:

- No problems in release
- VS2012 SP4 (v11.0.61030.00)
- problem persists when referencing member variables (iso no member references)
- TODO: try without global statics

Comment: Wonder if `this` is invalid in the debugger because you are not referencing anything in the current object.  In other words, maybe the compiler/debugger are not putting anything correct in `this` because it is not used?   What happens if you reference a class variable, for example, in `Foo()`?  I have seen the compiler do strange optimizing things like this when `this` is not referenced.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy optimization is off, in my full blown code I _was_ referencing member variables and that's how I noticed it. The heap (?correct?) gets corrupted anyway, variables are not what I assign them: eg in `locals` window `a` and `b` are garbage instead of `2.214`. Just added a member variable to this MCVE and tested it: still no `this` and data = garbage.

Comment: It all boils down to the mysterious `and esp,0FFFFFFF8h`. If it were missing from the first snippet then: a) `ebp = esp + 0f0h` thus `mov [esp+0f0h], ecx` and `mov [ebp-08h], ecx` (the `mov [this], ecx`) would denote the same offset relative to the frame pointer b) the `add/cmp/call` could be used (`and` is destructive so the stack pointer is restored with a `mov` from its saved value in `ebp`. The `xor` trick is a common way to negate numbers with a sign bit (like FP) as it flips a single bit. By using `-1.0 * a` you are asking a different operation to the (optimisations-unaware) compiler.

Comment: I don't know why VS introduces a stack alignment (at 8 bytes?). Maybe the `-a` triggers the xor trick that is usually associated with 64-bit code and that triggers the stack alignment? Then the debugger, which is known to be buggy, fails to reconstruct the frame and to match the debug symbols? Or there is a mismatch between the latter and the code generated?

Comment: You probably have undefined behaviour somewhere else in the program. Maybe a static initialization order problem, since you mentioned global statics

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'll have to read some more in the assembly guide to understand your reasoning :) thanks for the hints. I'm guessing it might be realted to this compiler bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1149857/debugging-c-routines-that-use-heavily-stack-in-visual-studio-is-corrupted

Comment: @M.M when I inspect the `dumpbin` of the object file generated by the compiler of the faulty class, this assembly is in there; I thought each compilation unit gets compiled on its own (at least without optimization), so UD elsewhere cannot generate this erroneous code (correct me if I'm wrong). As I've explained, the object data is there, but it doesn't get to where it belongs. This is also the first piece of code that's being run, callstack: `_tmain`>`WinMain`>`AfxWinMain`>`InitInstance` = code above

Comment: VS2012 had the first C++ compiler version that started to support automatic vectorization.  The stack alignment that Margaret noted is one pretty visible side-effect of it.  So is the lack of FPU instructions, all floating point math is done with SSE.  Big changes, not entirely without problems.  Be sure you have all updates installed, they are important.  Keeping the VS version is important too, lots of C++1x swirling. The sledgehammer solution is /arch to disable SSE codegen.

Comment: Maybe won't help at all but you might want to check this possibility.

I saw similarly strange behavior when we had an One Definition Rule break in our project.

Comment: I dont think what you see in the big project has something to do with the machine Code generated by your test Project. Your test method doesnt use any reference to the object and so the compiler might or might not generate code to reflect the this pointer. All the generated code above will work. Better you take a look for classical C/C++ error patterns in the legacy code. Good luck.